# jQuery event listening on a specific body with class "x"

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm reading about creating custom events and acting accordingly once they are fired
and it seems to only why to capture the event is by using the $(document) selector

```
$(document).on("formValid", function() {
    alert("form was valid");
});
```

The thing is, I have a class name called "x" on some of the pages body class
and would like to listen to events by using the .x selector. e.g:

```
$(".x .signupform").on("formValid", function() {
    alert("form was valid");
});
```

But that alert never fires.. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Please note:

I'm covered regarding the form validation and its behavior. What I need to know is why the first snippet of code in my question works, while the second doesn't.

Comment: You can try using trigger();

Comment: Please post markup as well - sure that your form has not both `.x` _and_ `.signupform` classes? In that case, you'd need `.x.signupform` [without space] selector.

Comment: `$(document).on("formValid", function() { if($('.x').length){ /* do stuff */  }  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`".x .signupform"` for `"formValid"` event:

```
$(".x .signupform").on("formValid", function() {
    alert("form was valid");
});
```

Who triggers `"formValid"` event? You must trigger it:

```
$(".x .signupform").trigger("formValid");
```

Then the alert will be fired.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TUc7w/)

Comment: I have another function which takes care of the form validation. Once that function has determined the form is valid, I trigger the event using: $.event.trigger({type: "formValid"}) - BTW your fiddle only works when the same selector is triggering the event.. hope you could help :)

Comment: @elad.chen Use `$(".x .signupform").trigger("formValid");` instead of `$.event.trigger({type: "formValid"})`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it.. :)